# iOS NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

My app fetches resources from AWS bucket (accessed thru a cloudfront).
**Some** of the users fails to fetch the data due to

```
NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
```

As we use AWS service I assume that the SSL certificate is fine, the fact that it happens to a small (but not small enough) portion of the users should say that the SSL certificate is OK.

Any other post I saw about this issue suggested to add a flag to `App Transport Security Settings` in info.plist file that will allow unsecured connection. This is not something I can (or want) to do.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

- This *might* happen if you're using a VPN.
- But will also happen if you're using a proxy tool like Charles Proxy but haven't installed/trusted the Charles Proxy certificate.
- It also happened to me when I was on a public wifi network. It seemed that some how the public wifi was doing some sort of a MITM to maybe add some ads. I didn't face the same problem when I was using LTE or a non-public wifi

Answer (score 0):

I found [this solution](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/112887) from the Apple Developer Forums which does not involve modifying the `App Transport Security Settings`:

> And you shouldn’t need an ATS exception in your scenario.  The
> approach I recommend is as follows:
>
> - Set up a custom certificate authority (CA) within your organisation (many organisations already have this).
> - Have it issue a certificate for your private server.
> - Use MDM to install your organisation CA’s root certificate on your devices.

Comment: Thanks! As I don't use a private server but AWS s3 + cloud front (with AWS SSL certifiactes) I don't think that this fits me.