# How to do an HTTP GET request in Swift 5 with an API-Key?

Tags: json, swift, api, swift5, api-key

To complete my project I have to fetch data from a json data. The company gave me an url : "https://intern.docker-dev.d-tt.nl/api/house",
and an Api key : "Access-Key : 98bww4ezuzfePCYFxJEWyszbUXc7dxRx" (this is not sensitive data)

To check the data I tried a cURL request as this :
"curl https://intern.docker-dev.d-tt.nl/api/house
-H "Access-Key : 98bww4ezuzfePCYFxJEWyszbUXc7dxRx"

and could see the JSON data. However I'm trying to code this in Swift 5 but I am having troubles.

I see many tutorials that use the "TRN-Api-Key" but I understood that I should use "Access-Key".

I guess I'm missing something but I can't see what.

I've tried this function but it's not working at all :

```
func fetchPostData(completionHandler : @escaping ([House]) -> Void) {

    if let url = URL(string: "https://intern.docker-dev.d-tt.nl/api/house") {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("98bww4ezuzfePCYFxJEWyszbUXc7dxRx", forHTTPHeaderField: "Access-Key")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do{
                let postsData = try JSONDecoder().decode([House].self, from: data)
                completionHandler(postsData)
            }
            catch{
                let error = error
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Edit : here is the House structure :

struct House: Codable {
let id: Int
let image: String
let price, bedrooms, bathrooms, size: Int
let welcomeDescription, zip, city: String
let latitude, longitude: Int
let createdDate: String
}

It seems that the problem is in fetching the data because the condition at this line is not validated :
"guard let data = data else { return }"

I've tried to remplace  "let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)" by " let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)" but it doesn't seem to change anything for now.

Here is my curl request :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTyxp.png

Here is the print of the error :

```
error:  Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
    "<cert(0x12a844600) s: docker-dev.d-tt.nl i: R3>",
    "<cert(0x12a843c00) s: R3 i: ISRG Root X1>",
    "<cert(0x12a844e00) s: ISRG Root X1 i: DST Root CA X3>"
), NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://intern.docker-dev.d-tt.nl/api/house, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://intern.docker-dev.d-tt.nl/api/house, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000003596b0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x600003c30be0>, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
    "<cert(0x12a844600) s: docker-dev.d-tt.nl i: R3>",
    "<cert(0x12a843c00) s: R3 i: ISRG Root X1>",
    "<cert(0x12a844e00) s: ISRG Root X1 i: DST Root CA X3>"
)}}, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <CE731702-E28A-4BB6-86BF-E78988FD242E>.<1>"
), _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <CE731702-E28A-4BB6-86BF-E78988FD242E>.<1>, NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x600003c30be0>, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.})
```

and here is the print of the response :

response:  nil

Comment: `print(error.localizedDescription)` => `print(error)`, and tell us what's the output of that. Also, could you show use `House` and what looks like your response with `print("ResponseStr: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")` And maybe print `response` too.

Comment: May be the problem in the response parsing?

Comment: using `curl ...`, I get "....SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired"

Comment: you could try using: `...URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)`, instead of `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)`.

Comment: Good point, the request (with header) isn't used, you should have an issue at some poiint.

Comment: @workingdog so I've tried your correction but it doesn't fix it ; however in trying to do print error I've seen that my program doesn't print the error, I understand that the condition "guard let data = data else { return }" is not valid. So the problem seems to be in the fetching of the data. By the way here is my House structure : struct House: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let image: String
    let price, bedrooms, bathrooms, size: Int
    let welcomeDescription, zip, city: String
    let latitude, longitude: Int
    let createdDate: String
}

Comment: What's the value of `error` & `response`?

Comment: @Larme just edited!

Comment: "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made" That's why you have an issue. Side note, I get also a SSL error with the cURL command. Fix that part if possible first

Comment: @Larme I don't really get what can I do... and btw my curl command works just fine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62876669/ios-nsurlerrordomain-code-1200-an-ssl-error-has-occurred-and-a-secure-connecti ? Look for the error. Do you own the server or are in contact with de dev? You might ask them.